# Django form wizard nested dynamic field creation

Tags: jquery, django, django-formwizard

I'm building a multi-step form with form wizard where a user enters some data, like so: Step1: User selects category from dropdown, (I assume I'll need to do some kind of ajax call here?), then a subcategory dropdown should appear, where he would choose again, then for step 2 I need to dynamically generate the fields, according to the subcategory.

```
#from models.py    
class Entity(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        value_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
```

Model use case example:

```
name      value_type      parent
Vehicles  select          null
Real estate select        null
.....
Cars      select          Vehicles
Bikes     select          Vehicles
.....
Mercedes  select          Cars
Audi      select          Cars
.........
A4        null            Audi
A5        null            Audi
```

etc.
So each of the subcategories has a very specific set of fields, all which are very different, with different pre-populated values and need to be generated one by one, within "Step 2" of the form. Say I choose Vehicles and Cars in step 1, step 2 should give me, say a Model dropdown(Mercedes,Audi...) then another dropdown should appear, depending on what I chose, prepopulated with Mercedes models etc. There are several levels of nested dropdowns like I described here. Been stuck on this for a week, nothing from SO/Google helped.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, but far less complex, using jquery/javascript. You can have the fields you need appear and disappear with custom js functions. If the top field is set to `Vehicle`, js can create the next fields, etc.

You can find the field name and id that the wizard is looking for by inspecting the default output in your browser. Usually the `name` is `your_step_name-your_field_name` and `id` is `id_your_step_name-your_field_name`.

You might also have to do some custom data handling in the wizard's `done` and `post` methods. I pretty much overwrite both of these every time I am doing something complicated with the wizards.

Hopefully that gets you started. It's possible to do what you are looking to do, if you are willing to use jquery.